# How to see what pages are using a specific template

Tags: web, dotcms

I am using dotCMS and would like to start consolidating some of our many templates into just a few. I need to know what web pages are using these templates, however, before I start deleting them and merging them.

How can I tell what webpages are using a specified template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your Website tab and navigate to HTML pages.

Once you're there, in the drop down menu select "Filter By Template: ", then in the blank, type your template name there and click search. This will give you a list of all pages running on that template.